# How to get set of objects added to modelmap in JSP

Tags: jsp, attributes

I am adding a set of objects to a ModelMap object with

```
  set<Contacts> contacts=user.getContacts();
  modelmap.addAttribute("objects",contacts);
```

How do I get the objects to display in JSP. I am using this method but cannot get the exact way of usage

```
  <c:foreach items="${objects}" var="xyz">
    <h1> ${xyz.name} </h1>
  </c:foreach>
```

How do I get the set of objects added.

When

```
  modelmap.addAttribute("object","hello");
```

and

```
  <h2>"object name is"</h2>
  <h1> ${object} </h1>
```

then it dispalys

object name is hello

now, if i add list of contacts, i need to access these contacts to display

Comment: What do you expect this code to do, and what dores it do instead?

Comment: In the controller i will be adding the list of contacts(contacts has different fields like name, numbers,addresses,etc) to modelmap. in my jsp, now i want to get those contacts which are added in the controller to modelmap and display them

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What does the above code do? What do you observe? What is printed on the screen? In the generated HTML page?

Comment: hi,thanq so much for ur interest in answering my que, i have answered ur question as answer to the main post to seperate the code section.

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question. You've described what you observe when you do something else. What do you observe when you do what's written in your question. Also, edit your question instead of answering it with something that's not an answer.